# Javascript fade out animation function (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, fadeout

So I made this function and it works:

```
var opacity = 9;

function func() {
    $("action").style.opacity = "0." + opacity;
    opacity--;

    if (opacity == -1) { window.clearInterval(fading); }
}

var fading = window.setInterval("func()", 200);
```

But thats acutally not really one single function.
So I did this:

```
function fadeOut(ms) {
    var opacity = 9;

    function func() {
        $("action").style.opacity = "0." + opacity;
        opacity--;

        if (opacity == -1) { window.clearInterval(fading); }
    }

    var fading = window.setInterval("func()", ms);
}

fadeOut(200);
```

And suddenly func() is undefined.
Help ? :|

Comment: The string `"func()"` is evaluated in *global* scope, but the function `func` is *local* to `fadeOut`. Pass a function reference instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
var fading = window.setInterval("func()", ms);
```

to

```
var fading = window.setInterval(func, ms);
```

Am not sure what `$("action")` return though, if its jQuery then style is not a valid member of $("action").